# How would I write the below code more efficiently?

Tags: r

How could I write the below code more efficiently (ie in less lines)?

I can't seem to define a function with a Year argument and write something like `Data{Year} = read.csv('{Year}.csv')` or `Data{Year}${Year+1} = 0` etc...

```
## Load data ##

Data2011 = read.csv('2011.csv')
Data2012 = read.csv('2012.csv')
Data2013 = read.csv('2013.csv')
Data2014 = read.csv('2014.csv')

## Year dummies ##

Data2011$D2011 = 1 
Data2011$D2012 = 0 
Data2011$D2013 = 0 
Data2011$D2014 = 0 

Data2012$D2011 = 0 
Data2012$D2012 = 1 
Data2012$D2013 = 0 
Data2012$D2014 = 0 

Data2013$D2011 = 0 
Data2013$D2012 = 0 
Data2013$D2013 = 1 
Data2013$D2014 = 0 

Data2014$D2011 = 0 
Data2014$D2012 = 0 
Data2014$D2013 = 0 
Data2014$D2014 = 1
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, I'd first read in the data in loop, and attach a new column with the year.

```
dat <- lapply(2011:2014, function(y) cbind(Year=y, read.csv(paste0(y, '.csv')))
```

Now, the most common use for dummies is when you're fitting a model, so I'm guessing you want to put all the data together.

```
dat <- do.call(rbind, dat)
```

Then in most model fitting you'd never make the dummies yourself, that's a job for the computer. You'd just make the variable of interest a factor and then R will do the right thing.

```
dat$Year <- factor(dat$Year)
```

That's all I'd normally do. But if for some reason I really wanted to make those dummies myself, I'd still let the computer do it, like this, and then add that to the data set.

```
dums <- model.matrix(~0+Year, data=dat)
dat <- cbind(dat, dums)
```

For the purpose of learning how to loop and access variables, you could also do something like this, where the `[[` allows you to use a character string to access or create a variable name, and the `*1` converts a boolean to 0/1.

```
for(y in unique(dat$year)) {
    dat[[paste0("Year", y)]] <- (dat$Year==y)*1
}
```